# JQuery: convert string to Date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert the string date "17/01/2018 12:34:56" to "2018-01-17 12:34:56" in JQuery.

Can anyone help me in this conversion.

Comment: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is for you

Comment: https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/10-ways-to-format-time-and-date-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks @asdf-enel-hak.. It worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). You can convert the string to formal date type easily, like this:

```
let date = moment('17/01/2018 12:34:56', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not done with jQuery but it's simple with built-in functions:

```
var d = "17/01/2018 12:34:56";
console.log( d.substr(0,10).split("/").reverse().join("/")+d.substr(10) );
```